# Can't install enum==0.4.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums, pip

my python version is 3.8.1 and I am not able to install enum==0.4.7

```
Collecting enum==0.4.7
  Using cached enum-0.4.7.tar.gz (20 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [8 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 11, in <module>
        File "C:\python381\lib\tokenize.py", line 32, in <module>
          import re
        File "C:\python381\lib\re.py", line 143, in <module>
          class RegexFlag(enum.IntFlag):
      AttributeError: module 'enum' has no attribute 'IntFlag'
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

It say :
**AttributeError: module 'enum' has no attribute 'IntFlag'**

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/enum/: "Project description, Important: Superseded by Python standard library". meaning that `enum` is already built-in the standard libaray - no need to install it with `pip`.

Comment: yes this helped me

Answer (score -2):

yes this helped to find my answer. I went through official enum site https://pypi.org/project/enum/ and description told me what i am looking for.
enum is standard library of python3. can't installed by pip